# Adding script tag to a flutter webapp widget

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have created a popup form with help of https://app.hubspot.com, it has provided a script tag and I want to show this form in a widget when the button "fill form" is clicked. I am unable to implement it. I tried adding it in index.html but not sure how to call it in a widget.